# Does mass updating contact records has any effect on Flex queues or Queues

Tags: contact, schedulebatch, update, apex-flex-queue, queueable

I have a requirement where I have to schedule a job daily to update records on the Contact object in batches via API(about 30,000 a day). Would that impact the Flex queue or Queues by any chance? Just want to make sure it does not exceed the Flex queue/Queue limit or it won't have any other negative impact.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Flex Queue has nothing to do with Scheduled jobs. You are limited to 100 scheduled jobs, though, so be aware of that limit. Such a daily scheduling would only have a maximum impact of 1 Flex Queue position if you already had five running batches at the time, and since you can have 100 such Batchable jobs queued, you'd only run in to a problem if you were already at 100 jobs. Your job will only ever occupy at most one Scheduled job slot and one Flex Queue slot.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am not sure if I understood it 100%. Are you saying scheduled jobs do not go to Flex queue? I am bit confused. What queue scheduled jobs go to? I was reading that Batch class in Salesforce use Flex Queues as well as asynchronous queue. Not sure what queue scheduled jobs go to?

Comment: ok so I was looking at this link
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000319687&type=1&mode=1
It sounds like Scheduled jobs stays in the Asynchronous queue/Apex job until the job is completed. So would it not ever go to Flex queue or would it go to Flex queue first and then Asynchronous queue since the data is going to be updated in batches via API?

Comment: @Student, What he means to say is you can have 100 async apex calls in holding status in flex queue at any point of time. As you are running only 1, you need not worry

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Also I am trying to understand the context behind mentioning 5 running batches at a time quoted below  "Such a daily scheduling would only have a maximum impact of 1 Flex Queue position if you already had five running batches at the time". Not sure what does that line mean?

Comment: @Student The Flex Queue only begins to fill if you have more than 5 concurrent batch processes running. Therefore, your plan will take up a "maximum" (at most) one slot in the queue, assuming you had other batches running concurrently. If you don't have any other batches running, it would run immediately and not consume a slot in the queue at all.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!!